# Matplotlib FuncAnimation 1st interval of graph not coming

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, data-visualization, visualization

I have the following code which creates a graph animation. The graph should start from 0, but the 1st interval graph isn't coming.
Below is the code:

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

left = -1
right = 2*np.pi - 1

def animate(i):
    global left, right
    left = left + 1
    right = right + 1
    x = np.linspace(left, right, 50)
    y = np.cos(x)
    ax.cla()
    ax.set_xlim(left, right)
    ax.plot(x, y, lw=2)

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval = 1000)

plt.show()
```

For the 1st interval [0, 2π] the graph isn't coming.
What's the mistake?

Comment: Have you tried to save the animation? Is the first frame in there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed a little bit your code:

- first of all I plot the first frame outside the `animate` function and I generate a `line` object from it
- then I update the `line` data within `animate` function
- I suggest to use `i` counter (which starts from `0` and increases by `1` in each frame) to update your data, in place of calling `global` variables and change them

### Complete Code

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

left = 0
right = 2*np.pi

x = np.linspace(left, right, 50)
y = np.cos(x)

line, = ax.plot(x, y)
ax.set_xlim(left, right)


def animate(i):
    x = np.linspace(left + i, right + i, 50)
    y = np.cos(x)

    line.set_data(x, y)
    ax.set_xlim(left + i, right + i)

    return line,

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig = fig, func = animate, interval = 1000)

plt.show()
```

[image]